# Gradient color for cells in NatTable using Style() and not CSS

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, nattable

I'm trying to apply a gradient in my Row Header and Column Header in NatTable. In the NatTable examples I can see that a CSS file has been used to apply gradient color in DarkExample. However I'm more interested in applying it through org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.style.Style.

Foreground gradient : left to right Red to White

Background gradient : Top to bottom Blue to White

Corner gradient : Top to bottom Red to White

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Everything that can be done via CSS can be done programmatically, as the CSS actually just forwards to the NatTable styling API.

That said, you can use the `GradientBackgroundPainter`. And this is also shown in the [CellPainterExample](https://github.com/eclipse-nattable/nattable/blob/master/org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.examples/src/org/eclipse/nebula/widgets/nattable/examples/_400_Configuration/_4222_CellPainterExample.java).